# Can we write compound sentences like this, using more than two conjunctions?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, compounds

**Example 1**

> I was going to mention the divorce rate, **but** I thought of the fact that children were there, **so** I did not really say it.

**Example 2**

> I was going to mention the divorce rate, **but** I thought of the fact that children were there and stopped, **and** my friend immediately brought up a new topic.

Can we write compound sentences like this, using more than two conjunctions?

Comment: The use of conjunctions in your sentences is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Yes, though "so" is not a coordinator but a connective adverb.